# I am missing some input fields in Openmodelica. Is there any way to turn them on?

Tags: openmodelica

I started working with OpenModelica a week ago. I am working mainly with OpenModelica Connection Editor. My goal is to simulate some pumps, tanks and control logic.
I put all the elements on the diagram view and I tried to set up everything in parameters tab, but I found out that I do not have same input fields as my colleagues?
When I open pump or tank parameters I do not have Medium input field (please see attachment).
When I open pump I do not have flow or efficiency characteristic (please see attachment).
I tried to solve this problem by simply adding Medium in text view, but then I got errors on not declared density or translation error that medium is not in the scope.
I tried to reinstall the program, but with no luck.
Could you kindly help me with this? Is there any way to turn on those fields? To be honest I am not even sure how much more fields I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The medium package is declared as replaceable package so that its component type can be changed in the future. About 2 years ago in OMEdit redeclaration of medium packages can only be changed in the text layer due to various reasons as reported in https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/2079. But now redeclaration can be implemented from the UI level similar to the dropdown list feature in Dymola.

Goto Tools--> Options --> General --> Optional features --> check 'Enable Replaceable Support'--> Press 'OK'

Note: Restart OMEdit once you do the above steps.

Now you can see the see 'Medium' selection in the Parameters window!!!

When you are playing with fluid components make sure that all of the connected models are having same medium type.

Comment: Hi!  Thank you very much for help, it worked and now I have every input field that I wanted/needed.  However I have another problem regarding it. I set everything and made sure I have same medium everywhere, but when I tried to run it I got Translation Error "output parameter d was not assigned a value". I don't see where I can set it. Could you help me with it also?